# VSTS Build failed on Get Sources

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build defined in VSTS that reports the following error if I try to run it:

```
Querying workspace information.

tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_1_1 /collection:https://myprojects.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt

TF14044: Access Denied: User Project Collection Build Service (WindwardProjects) needs the CreateWorkspace global permission(s).
Exit code 100 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_1_1 /collection:https://windwardprojects.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'.
```

I have checked and confirmed that the Project Collection Build Service user has "ALLOW" for the CreateWorkspace global permission, but I continue to get this error when the build reaches the point where it is trying to get the source code.  I have also checked the paths for the source code and everything seems correct... Can you provide any suggestions on what I might have missed, or other setup/configuration that might be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in VSTS account Security Tab https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_security, make sure **Create a workspace** is **Allow** for **Project Collection Valid Users**.

[image]